# json stringify duplicate key

Tags: javascript, json

I have a code that converts Html elements into JSON data. But it doesn't read all the elements with the same data key. If you run the code, you see that it has received the element 26 but has not received the element 24 (Online Register) . I think the reason is the dublicate-key error. I want code to take it all. How can I do ?

```js
var allmenus = $('.dragger-menu').map(function() {
  var li = {};
  $(this).children('li').each(function() {
    switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
      case "page":
        li.page = {
          id: $(this).data("menu-id")
        };
        break;
      case "external-link":
        li["external-link"] = {
          title: $(this).text().trim(),
          url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
          icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
        }
        break;
      case "dropdown":
        li.dropdown = {};
        li.dropdown.title = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
          return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
        }).text().trim();
        li.dropdown.data = $(this).children("ol").map(function() {
          var data = {};
          $(this).children("li").each(function() {
            switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
              case "page":
                data.page = {
                  id: $(this).data("menu-id")
                };
                break;
              case "external-link":
                data["external-link"] = {
                  title: $(this).text().trim(),
                  url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
                  icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
                }
                break;
            }
          });
          return data;
        }).get();
        break;
    }
  });
  return li;
}).get();

var obj = {
  menu: allmenus
};
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
console.log(jsondata);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="dragger-menu">
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="24">Online Register</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="26">Secondly Page</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="dropdown">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i> Dropdown Menu 
      <ol class="">
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="25">Contact Us</li>
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://twitter.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-Twitter"></i> Twitter</li>
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://facebook.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-Facebook"></i> Facebook</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
<ol class="dragger-menu">
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="28">Ahmet Deneme</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="21">Secondly Page</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change parent objects to have arrays for the children elements and `push()` to those arrays instead of over writing the whole property as you are currently doing

The following may not be 100% but will get you started

```js
var allmenus = $('.dragger-menu').map(function() {
  // arrays in parent for each group type
  var li = {page:[], "external-link":[], dropdown: []};

  $(this).children('li').each(function() {
    switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
      case "page": 
         // new page object instead of overwriting li.page 
         var page = {
          id: $(this).data("menu-id")
        };
        // push to array
        li.page.push(page)
        break;
      case "external-link":
        // new link object
        var link  = {
          title: $(this).text().trim(),
          url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
          icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
        }
        // push to array
        li["external-link"].push(link)
        break;
      case "dropdown":
        var dropdown = {};
        dropdown.title = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
          return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
        }).text().trim();
       dropdown.data = $(this).children("ol").map(function() {
          var data = {page:[],"external-link":[]};
          $(this).children("li").each(function() {
            switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
              case "page":
                data.page .push( {
                  id: $(this).data("menu-id")
                });
                break;
              case "external-link":
                data["external-link"].push( {
                  title: $(this).text().trim(),
                  url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
                  icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
                })
                break;
            }
          });
          return data;
        }).get();
        li.dropdown.push(dropdown)
        
        break;
    }
  });
  return li;
}).get();

var obj = {
  menu: allmenus
};
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
console.log(jsondata);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="dragger-menu">
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="24">Online Register</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="26">Secondly Page</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="dropdown">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i> Dropdown Menu 
      <ol class="">
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="25">Contact Us</li>
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://twitter.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-Twitter"></i> Twitter</li>
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://facebook.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-Facebook"></i> Facebook</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
<ol class="dragger-menu">
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="28">Ahmet Deneme</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="21">Secondly Page</li>
</ol>
```